# Calling jquery validation valid on form element

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I have a form where I am calling the valid() function on each form element separately. I have an field named "altemailaddress" that I set a rule to be "email" and required is false. However the valid() function returns false if there is no value in the input text box.

```
jQuery("#aspnet-form").validate({
    onsubmit: false,
    rules: {
        prefix: "required",
        emailaddress: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        altemailaddress: {
            required: false,
            email: true
        }

    },
    messages: {
        prefix: "Please enter a prefix",
        emailaddress: {
            required: "Please enter an email address",
            email: "Invalid email format"
        }

    }
});

var $group = jQuery(this).parents(".validationGroup");
    var isValid = true;


    $group.find(":input").each(function (i, item) {
        if (!jQuery(item).valid())
        {

            isValid = false;
        }           

    });
```

As I loop through each item, I call the valid() function. If the rule for altemailaddress says require: false,  it ignores it and returns false if no value is provided.

If I just set up the validate plugin to validate on submit it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think `valid()` is only for an enitre form

Try using `$.validate().element(item)`

```
if (!$("#aspnet-form").validate().element( item ))
{
  isValid = false;
}
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

Comment: This worked at first, then without changing any code, I tested again and now it doesn't work. I will have to try again

Comment: make sure you are still using jQuery 1.3
I had some sites start failing yesterday because they automatically started using jQuery 1.4, and some of the plugins didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution is a bit longer but works fine:

Let's say you have an input field "**Email**" like :

```
<input id="Email" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="Email" data-val-regex-pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" data-val-regex="Invalid email address." data-val="true"></input>
```

You can check if the value of the field matches the regex like this:

```
var emailreg = $('#Email').attr('data-val-regex-pattern');
if($('#Email').val().match(emailreg) != null){ //the field is valid }
```